# Uncalled components keeps leaking into other components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I was trying to implement a 404 page in React Redux as explained in [this article](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/guides/NotFound.html). My routes are as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {ConnectedRouter} from "react-router-redux";
import {Route} from "react-router";

import RootContainer from "../containers/RootContainer"
import NotFoundComponent from "../components/NotFoundComponent";

const routes = (history, store) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/" component={RootContainer}/>
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundComponent}/>
                </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default routes;
```

After this, I realized that the `NotFoundComponent` kept leaking into the `RootContainer`. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: I think your 404 route needs to be inside the root Route, just like in the link you added.

Comment: The duplicate answer solved it, but I'll try that also just in case